# Ubuntu 16.04LTS USB stick not showing up as a device in Clementine or Banshee

Tags: 16.04, music, banshee, usb-drive, clementine

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04LTS I have found that any USB Stick that I insert into the computer no longer appears as a device in Clementine or Banshee to enable me to transfer music over to the stick.

The USB Stick appears as a device in FILES (Nautilus) but doesn't show up in either Clementine or Banshee.

I've also tested this out using a LIVE CD of Ubuntu just to make sure it's nothing to do with the upgrade from 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS on my installation.[image: Screenshot of Clementine]

Has anyone else seen this and do you know how to get it to work.